# Link of wordpress menu item with submenu gets replaced with #

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap's navbar on my Wordpress menu. The main menu items are all linked to WP pages. One of these menu items have a submenu that consists of anchors on that page, but when I display the WP menu like this:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
        'depth'             => 2,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
    );
?>
```

The item that has a submenu loses its `href` to a page and gets replaced with `#` instead. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.